# SQL Server : calculate value of a column, using value of same column in previous rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like,

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpPercentage
( 
    ID INT,
    V1 VARCHAR(10),
    V2 FLOAT
);

INSERT INTO #tmpPercentage (ID, V1, V2)
VALUES (1, 'X', 10),
       (1, 'Y', 7),
       (1, 'Z', ?),
       (2, 'X', 15),
       (2, 'Y', 19),
       (2, 'Z', ?);
```

V2 for Z will be `(V2 for X * V2 for Y)/100` i.e. the percentage between x and y.

How do I calculate this? I am new to SQL. Thanks in advance

Comment: what value you want for z= ?

Comment: Do you want to update the table for `Z` or calculate on the `select`?

Comment: Hi Aruna. I want to update the current table

Comment: Mr Bhosale: I want Z to show percentage between X and Y. i.e., (x/y)*100

Answer (score 0):

Pivot the `X` and `Y` records to columns for each `ID` then do the calculation

Here is one way

```
select ID,
       Z = (max(case when V1 = 'X' then V2 end) * max(case when V1 = 'Y' then V2 end))/100.0
From #tmpPercentage
Group by ID
```

Above `Select` can be converted to `Update` query

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT ID,
                Z = ( Max(CASE WHEN V1 = 'X' THEN V2 END) * Max(CASE WHEN V1 = 'Y' THEN V2 END) ) / 100.0
         FROM   #tmpPercentage
         GROUP  BY ID)
UPDATE t
SET    V2 = c.z
FROM   #tmpPercentage t
       JOIN cte c
         ON t.ID = c.ID
WHERE  v1 = 'Z'
```

Considering there will be only one `X` and `Y` value for each `ID`. If you have more then one `X` and `Y` value for a `ID` then replace `Max` aggregate with `Sum` or `Avg` or `Min` based on your requirement.

Comment: Hi Prdp. Thanks for your response. This is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpPercentage
( ID INT,
  V1 VARCHAR(10),
  V2 FLOAT);

INSERT INTO #tmpPercentage
(ID, V1, V2)
VALUES (1, 'X', 10),
       (1, 'Y', 7),
       (2, 'X', 15),
       (2, 'Y', 19),
```

Then, do an insert for `Z` separately:

```
insert into #tmpPercentage
select id, 'Z', 
(max(case when V1 = 'X' then V2 end) * max(case when V1 = 'Y' then V2 end))/100.0
from #tmpPercentage
group by id, 'Z';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
; WITH tmpPercentage (ID,V1, V2) AS (
  SELECT 1, 'X', 10 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'Y', 7  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'Z', NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'X', 15 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Y', 19 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Z', NULL
  )
  SELECT ID, MAX(CASE WHEN v1='X' THEN V2 ELSE 0 END) *  MAX(CASE WHEN v1='Y' THEN V2 ELSE 0 END)/100.0 AS Z FROM tmpPercentage
  GROUP BY ID
```

```
ID          Z
----------- ---------------------------------------
1           0.700000
2           2.850000
```

```
  SELECT ID,V1,CASE WHEN V1='Z' THEN  
          MAX(CASE WHEN v1='X' THEN V2 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY ID)
        * MAX(CASE WHEN v1='Y' THEN V2 ELSE 0 END)OVER(PARTITION BY ID)/100.0 ELSE V2 END  AS V2 
  FROM tmpPercentage
```

```
ID          V1   V2
----------- ---- ---------------------------------------
1           Y    7.000000
1           Z    0.700000
1           X    10.000000
2           Y    19.000000
2           Z    2.850000
2           X    15.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CTE` as below to handle this without changing the order of the records and with single `INSERT` statement and no `UPDATE` statement.

**Note**: Just copy and paste the below statements into your local machine and give a try which will work like a charm :-)

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpPercentage
( ID INT,
  V1 VARCHAR(10),
  V2 FLOAT);


;WITH tmpPercentage0 AS (
   SELECT 1 AS ID, 'X' AS V1, 10 AS V2
   UNION
   SELECT 1 AS ID, 'Y' AS V1, 7 AS V2
   UNION
   SELECT 1 AS ID, 'Z' AS V1, NULL AS V2
   UNION
   SELECT 2 AS ID, 'X' AS V1, 15 AS V2
   UNION
   SELECT 2 AS ID, 'Y' AS V1, 19 AS V2
   UNION
   SELECT 2 AS ID, 'Z' AS V1, NULL AS V2
),
tmpPercentage1 AS (
    SELECT 
        *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RowNumber
    FROM  
        tmpPercentage0
)

INSERT INTO #tmpPercentage
    (ID,
     V1,
     V2)
SELECT 
    ID, V1, (
    CASE
        WHEN V1 = 'Z' THEN (
            (
                (SELECT CONVERT(FLOAT, V2) FROM tmpPercentage1 WHERE RowNumber = tp1.RowNumber - 2)
                *
                (SELECT CONVERT(FLOAT, V2) FROM tmpPercentage1 WHERE RowNumber = tp1.RowNumber - 1)
            ) / 100
        )
        ELSE V2
    END) AS V2
FROM 
    tmpPercentage1 tp1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a newer version of sql-server (such as 2012), you can use the **LAG** function which can return the previous row -

```
SELECT ID, V1
    , CASE
        WHEN V1 = 'Z'
        THEN ((LAG (V2, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY V1)) * (LAG (V2, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY V1))) / 100
        ELSE V2
      END AS V2
FROM #tmpPercentage;
```

Here

```
((LAG (V2, 1) and LAG (V2, 2)
```

returns the previous V2  and the V2 of two rows before the current row respectively.

```
OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY V1))
```

This ensures that the first we apply the LAG on each ID by using PARTITION BY
and then using V1 on the ORDER BY clause sort the rows from x, y, z. So it is important that all the x, y exist for a z. however this query will return correct result even for randomly ordered data -

```
INSERT INTO #tmpPercentage
(ID, V1, V2)
VALUES (1, 'X', 10),
       (2, 'X', 15),
       (1, 'Z', NULL),
       (2, 'Y', 19),
       (2, 'Z', NULL),
       (1, 'Y', 7);
```

**Output**

```
| ID | V1 | V2   |
|----|----|------|
| 1  | X  | 10   |
| 1  | Y  | 7    |
| 1  | Z  | 0.7  |
| 2  | X  | 15   |
| 2  | Y  | 19   |
| 2  | Z  | 2.85 |
```

**Note**: This query should be faster than any other versions which use sub queries.